# How to add count with each row's radio button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `count+` in each row like. In the first tr with all radio name should be `xRay1`. In the second tr with all radio name should be `xRay2`. What I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.changeRadioName').click(function() {
    $('.table tr').each(function() {
      var count = 1;
      $(this).find('input:radio[name="xRay"]').attr('name', count);
      count++;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="changeRadioName">Change name of each row's radio</button>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to get your result,
use counter variable out of the each function

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     
    $('.changeRadioName').click(function(){
            var count = 1;
    $('.table tr').each(function () {
                $(this).find('input:radio[name="xRay"]').attr('name', 'xRay'+count);
    
                count++;
            });
         });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <button class="changeRadioName">Change name of each row's radio</button>
    
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can loop through each `tr` and find the radios within it. Then you can use the index of the current `tr` and append it to the current `name` of the radio, something like this:

```js
$('.changeRadioName').click(function() {
  $('.table tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find(':radio').prop('name', function(_, name) {
      return name + (i + 1);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="changeRadioName">Change name of each row's radio</button>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     
    $('.changeRadioName').click(function(){
var count = 1;
    $('.table tr').each(function () {
            
                $(this).find('input:radio[name="xRay"]').attr('name', "xRay"+count);
                count++;
            });
         });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <button class="changeRadioName">Change name of each row's radio</button>
    
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
              <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`$(this).find('input:radio[name="xRay"]').attr('name', 'xRay'+(i+1));`

Here I am using `i` instead of counter, which is the index of the element and is the first argument of the function callback for the `each` method in jQuery. I am also using your same code, however, it is slightly modified, as I am concatenating the current index+1 (`i+1`) with the word `xRay`:

`.attr('name', 'xRay'+(i+1));`

See working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.changeRadioName').click(function() {
    $('.table tr').each(function(i) {
      $(this).find('input:radio[name="xRay"]').attr('name', 'xRay'+(i+1));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="changeRadioName">Change name of each row's radio</button>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnYes" name="xRay" value="true" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="trBtnNo" name="xRay" value="false" /> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `count` should be initialized outside `tr` loop and `attr` should assign `xRay + count` to every radio button.

Final jQuery code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.changeRadioName').click(function() {
      var count = 1;
    $('.table tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find('input:radio[name="xRay"]').attr('name', 'xRay' + count);
      count++;
    });
  });
});
```